# Is there any way to get the information about admin who installed my app?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am developing an application for the Google Apps Marketplace.

I use the [Licensing API](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/) to retrieve the notifications. I need to get the information about admin,  who installed the app, but the API doesn't provide me with this.

The solution I found is to use [the Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_domain_users) to search users, but I get an error

```
{
    "error": {
     "errors": [
      {
       "domain": "global",
       "reason": "forbidden",
       "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
      }
     ],
     "code": 403,
     "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my request? 
Are there any other solutions to get the information about admin?

The auth scopes:

```
- "email"
- "profile"
- "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
- "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
- "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly"
- "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly"
```

Comment: Check this other question, it will probably help you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409201/google-service-directory-403-not-authorized-to-access-this-resource-api)

Comment: @AlexanderV Did you find any solution? what happend when the admin of the domain is not admin@yourdomain.com?

Comment: I used Directory API.   https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AlexanderVorkov/posts/gNGvH5G15QR