# How to get a list of user of domain after the admin install my app?

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace

I published an app to the google marketplace. 
I can know which domain installed my app through the licenseNotification, but to get the list of users from the usersService I need the mail of the admin.
How can I get who the admin of the domain or the list of all users?

I checked those two questions:

[Is there any way to get the information about admin who installed my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891704/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-information-about-admin-who-installed-my-app)

[Google_Service_Directory - (403) Not Authorized to access this resource/api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409201/google-service-directory-403-not-authorized-to-access-this-resource-api)

But i'm facting a domain which the admin is not admin@some_domain.com

Comment: To list the users of domain, its not enough just to get admin email, you should be admin of the domain. or admin of the domain should give you domain wide delegation and impersonate you. To get the admin of the domain, even in admin console, only admin has rights to check admin of the account.

Comment: I refer to a situation that the admin of the domain install my app from marketplace to all the users in the domain, in this case with the ServiceAccount i can list the users of the domain with the permissions of the admin, my problem is that I don't know the mail of the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments on https://plus.sandbox.google.com/u/0/+AlexanderVorkov/posts/gNGvH5G15QR

The solution right now is to configure a setup URL for your application. This URL is displayed to the admin at the end of the installation. You can use that setup process to gather the missing info (admin identity/email) and do whatever you need to finalize setup.

There is the possibility that the admin won't visit that URL right away. Your app needs to be robust and handle cases where the admin hasn't completed setup yet users still try to access the app (e.g. treat that setup as optional, give end-users a friendly message asking them to contact their admin, etc.)