# access user profile information in a google domain with python

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, api-key

Objective: my python web app access a google user's information from a customer. They already provided authorization to service account to access the scope of admin.directory.user.readonly and Im using this service account JSON file as credential to my app.
credential_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(app.instance_path), 'cre.json')
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly']
PATH_TO_CREDENTIALS = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
GET_CREDENTIALS = PATH_TO_CREDENTIALS
PASS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(GET_CREDENTIALS, scopes=SCOPES)

service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=PASS_CREDENTIALS)

# Call the Admin SDK Directory API
print('Getting the first 10 users in the domain')
results = service.users().list(customer='customer.com', domain='customer.com', maxResults=10, orderBy='email').execute()
users = results.get('users', [])

for user in users:
    print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(user['primaryEmail'], user['name']['fullName']))
```

Im getting:

`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=nidec-ga.com&domain=nidec-ga.com&maxResults=10&orderBy=email&alt=json returned "Bad Request". Details: "Bad Request">`

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `domain` and `customer` on the same GET request. In the Admin Google API documentation, it states the following for the `domain` field:

- The domain name. Use this field to get fields from only one domain. To return all domains for a customer account, use the customer query parameter instead. Either the customer or the domain parameter must be provided.

Comment: it resolved the bad request issue thanks, now got 403 not authorized, but I asked the domain owner to add authorization to scope admin.directory.user.readonly for the app credential that we are using, am I missing anything else? thanks a lot

Comment: Assuming your OAuth request authorization is correctly setup, your issue might be related to this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243221/403-error-from-google-admin-sdk-with-appassertioncredentials

Comment: @GustavoCastanheira - This answer plus you need impersonation. `creds = PASS_CREDENTIALS.with_subject(EMAIL_ADDRESS)`

Comment: @GustavoCastanheira - This link will help understand my comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account