# Service account not Authorized to access this resource/api while trying to access directory api using Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-directory-api

We use Python to get all users from a particular G Suite managed domain, but after completing the following [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) and granting all the access needed to the Service Account, the following snippet still produces "Not Authorized to access this resource/api:

```
import json
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly']

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/path/to/file.json", scopes=SCOPES)

service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a (very vague) clue in [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to the solution:

> Note: Only users with access to the Admin APIs can access the Admin
>   SDK Directory API, therefore your service account needs to impersonate
>   one of those users to access the Admin SDK Directory API.
>   Additionally, the user must have logged in at least once and accepted
>   the G Suite Terms of Service.

The way to achieve the impersonation in Python is by sending a "subject" when authenticating with OAuth2 library. The subject should be a user with an access to the Admin API (He doesn't have to be an admin, User Management Role should be sufficient, at least for my needs).

A working snippet:

```
import json
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly']

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/path/to/file.json", scopes=SCOPES, subject="admin@yourdomain.com")
```

Comment: Can you please help what role should I give to subject , I searched but colud not found user management role

Comment: also how can I give access to admin api

Comment: O my god, I can sleep tonight! Using my workspace admin account/project owner email as subject worked. Why was this nowhere in the documentation???