# Not able to call directory APIs

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

we would need to integrate with GSuite API to retrieve the group members and the user details of them by a daily job.

I've followed the guide and:

1. setup a service account
2. enabled "Admin SDK" at "Google Cloud console"
3. checked "Enable API access" at GSuite "Google Admin" -> "API Reference"
4. granted permission to the service account at "Manage API client access" with the following:

   1. View group subscriptions on your domain  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly
   2. View groups on your domain  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly
   3. View users on your domain  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly

However the response I got when I try to call:
 - https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{group id}/members, or
 - https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/{user email}

I got "Not Authorized to access this resource/api".

I've tried to use CURL to exchange access token, and tried to use JAVA SDK, both returned the same error.

Please let me know if I've missed out anything. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you set the [service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409201/google-service-directory-403-not-authorized-to-access-this-resource-api) as administrator of the domain?

Comment: may I know how to do this? In GSuite Admin console, it will show "User does not exists"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the missing part.

In case anyone face the same problem, simply add "sub=[super admin]@[your domain]" when exchanging the accessToken. This will solve the problem.