# Google Admin SDK - "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" when updating delegated Admins

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am using the `.NET` API to provision user accounts. I am having a problem when trying to update a user who has delegated admin privileges as a member of one of the builtin admin roles such as the "**Password Reset Role**". If I remove them from the role the account is updated successfully. When a member, I cannot update `orgUnitPath`, `givenName`, or `familyName`. I am able to update the custom attributes that have been added.
Anyone know if this a bug or feature? I am using version `1.36.1.1335` of the `Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.dll` library.

Comment: Have you tried to checked this SO post with same error - [Google_Service_Directory - (403) Not Authorized to access this resource/api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409201/google-service-directory-403-not-authorized-to-access-this-resource-api)?

Comment: For anyone interested I was able to resolved the issue. Something I left out was I was using a service account to run the process against. I also created a dedicated account for the service account to impersonate. Since the account was dedicated for this process no one had ever logged in using that account. Once I logged in I stopped getting the "Not Authorized" error messages. Also, the dedicated account needs to be a Super Admin. At first it was only a member of the Groups Admin and User Management Admin roles.