# Is there a way to search from the list of groups in a domain by a non-admin user?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

The Directory API throws a 'Not Authorized to access this resource/api' error when I try to list the groups in a domain as a non-admin. But gmail autocompletes the group names (which means it is able to retrieve the list of groups) for non-admin users as well. Is there a way to get the list of groups or search from the list of groups in a domain without being an admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do if you are not an admin user, is to impersonate the admin by using a service account. You need to enable domain-wide delegation for your service account to impersonate a domain admin when making a request. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409201/google-service-directory-403-not-authorized-to-access-this-resource-api) and another discussion for [this github post](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/615).

Comment: Thanks! I get the idea, but my question is - is there any other way out? (apart from being or impersonating the admin) Some other API perhaps?